# Select rows where datetime = date and still use index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with a `datetime` column which is indexed.  I'd like to select all the rows for a specific date.  Previously I've been using this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE DATE(date_column) = '2016-04-12';
```

This works fine, however I've been noticing performance issues due to the fact that MySQL does not make use of the index once I apply the `DATE()` function.  I've also tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE SUBSTR(date_column,1,10) = '2016-04-12';
```

to no avail.  So far the only thing that seems to work is:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE date_column >= '2016-04-12'
    AND date_column < '2016-04-13'
```

This last query successfully uses the index but I'd like to know if there is a way to do this with only a single condition.

Comment: Why not `date_column = '2016-04-12 00:00:00.000'` on your first query? Or in a range between that and the last second of 2016-04-12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this code pattern; it is clear, precise (no confusion over midnight), and can use the index:

```
WHERE date_column >= '2016-04-12'
  AND date_column  < '2016-04-12' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

It even works 'correctly' for `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, `DATETIME(6)`, etc.

`'2016-04-12 00:00:00.000'` is identical to `'2016-04-12'` when used in this context.  I prefer the latter because it is more concise.

Comment: thanks, this is very similar to what I've already got - granted I've revised the last query to work properly.  but the question I'm asking is for a way to do this with only one condition.

Comment: You need the "range" in order to get the index to be used.  (Yeah, the optimizer should be smarter, but it is not.)